# Mainframe job dependency in SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, db2, ssms, mainframe

I have a SQL Server job which has to check if the mainframe DB2 job is complete (for the data) and then run the SSIS packages. I plan to add step 1 to check if the job is complete. I cannot add the job name directly in stored procedure which is one of the ways we write two SQL jobs dependency. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Can you issue a REST call?  There are z/OSMF REST APIs which can be used to check job status.
GET /zosmf/restjobs/jobs/&jobname/&jobid

For more information:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.izua700/IZUHPINFO_API_GetJobStatus.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like Patrick Bossman's idea primarily because it's polling, but also because the competency to determine reliably whether the Db2-related job has completed successfully is on that machine itself. It's best not to try to second guess successful completion and to handle errors. The mainframe is almost surely already doing all that.

Assuming batch-oriented data flows even make sense for the end users and their needs, it'd be much better if the IBM Z machine itself pushed some kind of notification downstream after it completes its job step. I'll assume this machine is running the z/OS operating system, but please post a follow-up if my assumption is not correct.

There are a variety of ways for z/OS to "tap" some other system on the shoulder, as it were. One rather straightforward way is to use the job scheduler to do it. For example, if you're running IBM Z Workload Scheduler (likely the most common job scheduler on z/OS), there are a huge variety of notice "taps" available to issue. They're explained in this documentation (current version link as I write this, subject to change):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRULV_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/eqqlwmst.pdf

As one pattern, IBM Z Workload Scheduler can continue handling whatever DB2-related job step this is, and then when the job completes successfully IBM Z Workload Scheduler can use its MSSQL job type to directly notify Microsoft SQL Server to run its job. Search in the publication linked above for "MSSQL" to find those references. Other "taps on the shoulder," such as a Web service call, are also available if you don't like the MSSQL type for some reason.

Other job schedulers on z/OS likely have analogous capabilities. And whoever handles job scheduling, if that's not you, should be able to work with you to get a "tap on the shoulder" added to the scheduler.

If there's more information available on the data flows and their business context, I may have some other suggestions.